# WordPress in a container fails to connect to a MySQL container on an ECS Fargate cluster

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

WordPress is failing to authenticate the `bn_wordpress` mysql user with the MySQL database when the two containers run on an ECS cluster on Fargate.  How do I fix this?

**Logs**

The WordPress ECS Task container logs this error to the CloudWatch log for the ECS Task:

```
mysql-c INFO Found MySQL server listening at localhost:3306
mysql-c ERROR [canConnect] Connection with 'bn_wordpress' user is unsuccessful
```

The MySQL container ECS task CloudWatch log reports `ready for connections` just like the container does when I run it on an EC2 instance with `docker-compose up -d`.

```
2020-05-19T20:07:31.302870Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20' socket: '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' port: 3306 Source distribution.
```

I'm asking myself if should I keep going or should I just give up on WordPress and MySQL.

**Environment Variables**

Here's are the environment variables portions of docker-compose.yml.

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: 'bitnami/mysql:8.0'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=bn_wordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bitnami_wordpress
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  wordpress:
    image: 'bitnami/wordpress:5'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8443:8443'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_HOST=localhost
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER=bn_wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_wordpress
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
```

**Probably not the authentication plugin**

Docker Compose runs the two containers on an EC2 instance with the Bitnami docker-compose file for [WordPress with MySQL](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress/blob/master/docker-compose-mysql.yml). WordPress responds to `curl http://localhost:8080`.  That's why I don't think this is the `default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` problem. I'm sorry if it is.